# Custom Post Type Alerts

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I setup a custom post type and everything works right. The user can submit for review and I see it's pending in the admin area. How can I have WordPress send me an Email Notification whenever a user submits a post?

```
add_action( 'init', 'artwork_feature');
function artwork_feature() {
register_post_type( 'artwork',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Artwork' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Artwork' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    'capability_type' => 'artwork',
    'supports' => array('custom-fields', 'comments'),
        'capabilities' => array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_artworks',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_artworks',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_artwork',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_artworks',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_artwork',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_artwork',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_artwork',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_artwork',
            'read_post' => 'read_artwork',
        ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')

    )
);
}
```

Comment: Is this something you've custom built? It is a plugin? By comments do you mean like Post Comments you would make on a blog? When you create a Post Type you should be able to set the option `'supports' => array('comments')` [View Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)

Comment: I set it up in functions.php and I do have it set to supports => comments but I don't get any notifications. Yes I am talking about post comments which does work as expected. I added my code.

Comment: Is this not possible?

Comment: I've tested this with my Post Type and I get the Red (1) whenever somebody posts a comment. If you want email notifications, checkout `Settings->Discussion`

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm not making myself clear, let me try again. I want a notification when a user creates new content that is post type = artwork, thanks!

Comment: I see, and when new users create content, is it pending or is it automatically published?

Comment: It is pending, that's why I would like the notification, so I can quickly approve if necessary.

Comment: If you want **Email Notifications** on post change - that's a whole other can of worms. This is not something that's built into WordPress by default. You are better off finding a suitable plugin such as [EditFlow](http://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-flow/) or [Email Post Changes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/email-post-changes/)

Comment: I was able to find what I wanted with: Post Status Notifier Lite

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook, which is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated.

Add something like this below to your functions.php:

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $subject = 'A post has been updated';

    $message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
    $message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;

    // Send email to admin.
    wp_mail( 'admin@example.com', $subject, $message );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
```

*One thing to note is that your localhost by default will not send out an email to an external source - unless you have configured it. There is however a couple of plugins that will allow you to send via SMTP, that way you can easily test from localhost.*

The example above is taken from the [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) codex page, however in addition to the above, you would want to add filters to only send it out for your custom post type and not every post, as well as maybe just for a fresh create rather than all updates (by specifying which [post status](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-status/) you want alerts for) - up to you to decide.

All the best, 
Kat

Comment: thank you. worked perfectly